# How to reference indexPath in prepareForSegue function (Swift 2.0)

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm new to Swift, and I've been scavenging StackOverflow for a couple hours trying to find a solution. This is what I have so far (that doesn't show a compilation error):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "addExpenseSegue"
    {

        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! AddExpenses

        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        destination.itemNameText = self.items[indexPath!.row] 
    }
}
```

Basically I have an array of user-entered items, and I click a button to segue into another view controller that displays the selected item as a label. I'm trying to relay the contents of my tableView into a second view controller (called AddExpenses) in the form of a label.

If I write `destination.itemNameText = "hey"` the code works just fine.

Also, here's the code from my second view controller:

```
class AddExpenses: UIViewController

{
    var itemNameText = String()
    @IBOutlet var ItemName: UILabel!

    @IBAction func CancelButton(sender: AnyObject)
    {

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        ItemName.text = itemNameText
    }
```

How can I get `indexPath.row` inside the `prepareForSegue` function? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here's some more of my code. This is inside my main view controller:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Labels stuff inside table
    cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

// Does the swiping action for each cell
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
{
    let deletedRow:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Delete")
    {
        action, index in
        self.items.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row) // Take word out of the array
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic) // Remove entire row
        deletedRow.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None // Take out checkmark
    }
    delete.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(0xff6347)

    let bought = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Bought")
    {
        action, index in

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("addExpenseSegue", sender: self)

    }

    bought.backgroundColor = UIColorFromHex(0x43CD80)

    return [bought, delete]
}
```

Comment: Edited the question to provide more code!

Answer (score 0):

Update your prepareForSegue  method to

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "addExpenseSegue"
    {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! AddExpenses
        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        destination.itemNameText = self.items[indexPath!.row]
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I get this error: Could not cast value of type 'ViewController' (0x1000c2218) to 'UITableViewCell' (0x19fdf3728). Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the index path in `performSegueWithIdentifier`

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("addExpenseSegue", sender: indexPath)
```

and get it in `prepareForSegue`. Since the sender of `prepareForSegue` could also be the table view cell you have to check the type

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   if segue.identifier == "addExpenseSegue" {
      let indexPath : NSIndexPath
      if sender is UITableViewCell {
          indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)
      } else {
          indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath
      }
     ...
```

Comment: I get the error: Cannot convert value of type 'NSIndexPath' to expected argument type 'UITableViewCell'

Comment: Then the segue is not called by the code in `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`. It seems that the segue is also connected to the cell in Interface Builder. I updated the answer.

Comment: Ah, okay, so I did that but still doesn't work. I think I probably set up something wrong. Anyway, I changed my app design and decided to go with a simpler implementation. I'll leave this question up here in case anyone needs it in the future. Thanks for your help!